# WPF get inserted inline from applypropertyvalue

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox (CurRichTextControl) and I change the TextDecoration of selected text:

```
TextRange range = new TextRange(CurRichTextControl.Selection.Start, CurRichTextControl.Selection.End);
TextDecorationCollection tdc;
tdc = TextDecorations.OverLine;
range.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, tdc);
```

WPF ist going to create a new Inline by that.
Lets say the Paragraph containing the range consists of only 1 Inline (or Run) prior to applying the TextDecoration.
Then it is going to result in 3 Inline elements after that.
How can I get the new Inline with the OverLine? ApplyPropertyValue does not return any value or object. Do I have to search the Paragraph manually?

Thank you!